# ReportViewer 10, ASPX, Paging Issues

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have a small web project, the sole purpose of this project is to house and produce reports for a larger application.

I have a page "ReportManager.aspx" that simply has a ReportViewer (10.0) control on it.

```
<div style="width:auto;">
    <form id="Form1" runat="server" style="width:100%; height: 100%;">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">          
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <rsweb:reportviewer id="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="100%"     AsyncRendering="false"  SizeToReportContent="true"></rsweb:reportviewer>
    </form>        
</div>

<script runat="server">
    private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        return;

        ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://localhost/ReportServer");
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/SSRSReport";
        ReportParameter param = new ReportParameter("effective_date", "4/22/2013");
        ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(param);
        ReportViewer1.PageCountMode = PageCountMode.Actual;
    }
</script>
```

Changing pages on the reportviewer control at runtime is producing an error.

The error is in:
Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=Resource&Version=10.0.30319.1&Name=ViewerScript

at Line 3559, and looks like this:

```
    // Remove the current STYLE element, if it already exists.
    if (oldStyleElement != null)
        headElement.removeChild(oldStyleElement);
```

`headElement.removeChild(oldStyleElement);` is the line where the error is showing htmlfile: Invalid argument. Break | Continue | Ignore.

Clicking "Continue" causes the report to render without any styling. Clicking "ignore" allows the report to render correctly.

I am running Windows 2012 Server, Visual Studio 2012 Premium and IE8. The same error occurs on Win 7 machines.

Any suggestions or known fixes?

Comment: I'm having this same problem (in v11 of the control) with an embedded ReportViewer in an MVC app and it's driving me up the wall.

Comment: I am using VS 2012 with the ReportViewer version 11 in a .Net 4 app; problem persists. I can print all pages but only view page 1 in browser. Anyone else encounter this a find a fix?

Answer (score 0):

My report is in an MVC app also. I actually fix this problem awhile ago. I think I fixed it by removing the following lines:

```
ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Remote;
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = new Uri("http://localhost/ReportServer");
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.ReportPath = "/SSRSReport";

ReportViewer1.PageCountMode = PageCountMode.Actual;
```

I changed the code to store all that data in the  tag.

Another thing I did was add 
ReportViewer1.ServerReport.Refresh() below ReportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(param).

After I made those changes, everything started working.

Comment: were you using IE8 by chance? I can only reproduce this with IE8 in an MVC app. Unfortunately, that's the target browser for this application. >:

Answer (score 0):

Though suspicious it would help, I tried removing as much code-behind as possible like you suggested, but this did not fix it for me.

**However, this was the solution in our app:**

> The .aspx page hosting the ReportViewer control was missing its `<body>` tag.

**THAT'S ALL**!!

Anti-climactic, I know, but apparently this causes IE8 (at least) to barf on

```
headElement.removeChild(oldStyleElement);
```

I'm curious if doing the same in your app brings the error back.

There are only a handful of resources I found via Google dealing with this problem, I can't believe this wasn't mentioned in any of them :-x

Comment: lol I thought you were right at first, then I realized I used the spoiler markdown. You have to hover to see it.

Comment: We are getting the same error in IE9 but the page where it is failing does have a body tag.  Wondering if anyone else found a different solution.